# How to end sessions if user closes the browser (X) instead of logout

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have seen multiple forums but I'm not clear on the solution.

1. When I try to invalidate the session in browser close event, my session is lost even on page refresh. I don't want my session to end on page refresh, I want my session to end on browser/tab close.
2. Can I invalidate my session on browser close event using angularJs ?

Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try out the HTML5 session storage. Data stored there will persist through refreshes but will be removed on page/tab closing. This should also work fine with Angular.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

```
// Set something
sessionStorage.set('usertoken', '123456789');
// Get something
sessionStorage.get('usertoken');
```

Comment: Eskil, this is for a single value. but how can I use this to end the session on browser close?

Comment: How are you handling your sessions? If it's token-based then the above should work. Otherwise it'll be hard. My suggestion is to either move to token-based auth or set a timeout for the session.